# parsing large textfile output to another textfile

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, text-files

I want to parse a large textfile and if the line contains a certain substring then append that line to my new text file.  I need the solution with the lowest memory usage, This is what I have so far, the comments is what I need help adding:

```
.
.
.
if (File.ReadLines(filepath).Any(line => line.Contains(myXML.searchSTRING)))
{

// code to grab that line and append it to the a new text file 
// if new text file doesn't exist then create it.
// All text files im parsing have the same header, I want to grab
// the third line and use it as my new text file header. 
// Only write the header once, I do not want it written every time a new 
// text file is opened for parsing 

}
```

Comment: You're appending each line into a separate text file?

Comment: How large is "Large"?

Comment: Im appending each line that .contains my search substring into a new text file.  My output is supposed to be only 1 new text file with all the appends.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You should include a sample of the output you want. Also, it seems like you're asking us to write the code for you, when you've done very little work yourself!

Comment: About 30 text files, 50-80MB each

Comment: Do you want to search multiple files for that string, and put all of the found lines into a single output file?

Comment: That is correct Jim... I already have a loop on top selecting each text file to parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it (edited to reflect @JimMischel's comments):

```
private static void WriteFile(string mySearchString, string fileToWrite, params string[] filesToRead)
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fileToWrite, true))
    {
        var count = 1;

        foreach (var file in filesToRead)
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                string line;

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (count == 3)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                    if (count > 3 && line.Contains(mySearchString))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(line);
                    }

                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
WriteFile("Foobar", "fileToWrite.txt", "input1.txt", "input2.txt", "input3.txt");
```

Comment: `ReadToEnd()` reads the entire file into memory. This is what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: Yep, saw that just after I posted :)

Comment: Thank you JMK for the answer

Comment: Rather than that convoluted use of `Peek`, you can just write `while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)`. Or, `while (!sr.EndOfStream)`. Or, you can get rid of 'most all that code and write `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename))`.

Comment: One other note: this adds the header to the output file for each input file, something that the OP specifically said he didn't want.

Comment: @JimMischel Updated my answer to clean up the stream reader code and only add header once, regardless of how many files are input

Answer (score 7):

Try :

```
var count = 1;
File.WriteAllLines(newFilePath, 
  File.ReadLines(filepath)
  .Where(count++ == 3 || l => l.Contains(myXML.searchSTRING))
);
```

Both `WriteAllLines()` and `ReadLines()` use enumerators, so should have relatively low memory usage.

I'm not sure how you would know to write the header only once, it depends on how you have your list of files to open available. Are they in an array? If so wrap the `File.WriteAllLines` call in a foreach loop around that array.

Comment: now he just needs the header.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  what do I need to import to use File.WriteLines?  Im getting a does not contain definiton error

Comment: I don't see a `File.WriteLines` in the documentation for the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) class. What am I missing? Do you mean `WriteAllLines`?

Comment: Sorry, yes, meant WriteAllLines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that :

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(outpuFilePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filepath).Where(line => line.Contains(myXML.searchSTRING)))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most important thing is to use "Where" instead of "Any" Any returns a true/false, if a collection matches, whereas you want to filter the collection.  Below should get you started in combination with the answers above (I would use Linq for clarity though).

```
StreamWriter outFile = new StreamWriter("output.txt");
string filepath = "infile.txt";
var header=File.ReadLines(filepath).Skip(2).First();
outFile.WriteLine(header);
var searchString = "temp";
File.ReadLines(filepath).Where(x => x.Contains(searchString))
.Select(x =>outFile.WriteLine(x));
```

Answer (score -1):

Please read article for MemoryMappedFile

http://www.dotnetperls.com/memorymappedfile-benchmark

Comment: An important read regarding MemoryMappedFile: [Memory Mapped File Quirks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/06/06/memory-mapped-file-quirks.aspx). Pay attenttion especially to chapter "**Subtle differences (B): Where are all those zeros coming from?**"

Comment: Two things. First, using a `MemoryMappedFile` will not reduce memory usage, which is the OP's stated goal. Second, this is about as helpful as saying, "use a `StreamReader`." This answer provides no useful information.